# Make/Remove USB Storage Devices as Read Only

Tags: filesystem, file-format

I just gave my 32GB flash stick to record the VDO for me. After that, I can only see the stuff in it. No *delete* or *cut*. It is set as "**Read Only**", and basically useless... Apparently this my `/dev/sdb1` is in "`vfat`" file format.

Is there a way that I could repartition (format) it, or do something so that I can use it again?

**edit**: I even tried these steps from [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F4lAlb74mGs), but my results were different:

```
   root@**:/home/*****# dosfsck -a /dev/sdb1
   fsck.fat 3.0.26 (2014-03-07)
   open: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 1):

Try remounting the device with `rw` access by:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw <mount-point-of-/dev/sdb1>
```

Comment: This is what I get:
     bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Comment: Do not include `<` and `>` in your code, they are just place holders. So if your mount point is for eg: `/media/my_usb`, then you should execute `sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/my_usb`. Use `mount` to see where exactly your device is mounted.

Comment: OK, I understood now. Unfortunately see this now: *mount: cannot remount /dev/sdb1 read-write, is write-protected*